# Layout issue using jQuery floatThead plugin(1.2.10) in IE10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm using jQuery floatThead plugin(version 1.2.10) to float header while scrolling the contents of a table but experiencing layout issues in IE10(works fine in chrome). Here's my code...

HTML:

```
<div class="scrollable-wrapper">
    <table id="tblDemo">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Student Name</th>
                <th>Course Name</th>
                <th>Is Completed</th>
                <th>Grade</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">John</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Science</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Maths</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Literature</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Peter</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Science</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Maths</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Literature</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Helen</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Science</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Maths</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Literature</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Rob</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Science</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Maths</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Literature</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Dave</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Science</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Maths</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Literature</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Tyson</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Science</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Maths</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Literature</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Danny</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Science</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Maths</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Literature</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Aahna</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Science</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>C</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Maths</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>B</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Literature</td>
                <td>Yes</td>
                <td>A</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/floatthead/1.2.10/jquery.floatThead.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
var $demo1 = $('#tblDemo');
$demo1.floatThead({
    scrollContainer: function () {
        return $demo1.closest('div');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.scrollable-wrapper {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

table{
    width:100%;
}
```

The resulting layout when viewed in IE10 has the row with student name "John" shifted to header row and hence invisible. This works fine in chrome. The issue seems to be due to row having only one TD with colspan set to 4 for printing student name. How can I fix it in IE10?

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dineshe/833eLyod/) for above code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. This was resolved by adding another option getSizingRow to floatThead options and it points to the row that does not have colspan in TD elements. Here's the updated code...

```
var $demo1 = $('#tblDemo');
$demo1.floatThead({
    scrollContainer: function () {
        return $demo1.closest('div');
    },
    getSizingRow: function($element) {
        return $element.find('tbody tr:nth-child(2)>*');
    }
});
```

Comment: Alternatively you could  try `$table.floatThead({headerCellSelector: 2});`

Comment: my thead had the total amount of <th>'s so i just provided the selector for that which worked fine: $table.('thead tr>*');